# Reload CMFCMenuBar from resource dynamicaly

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to reload CMFCMenuBar from menu resource by its ID correctly?
My main frame (CFrameWndEx) contains menu bar (CMFCMenuBar) and some time it should fully switch menu bar from one set to other. Both set are solid and exist in resource.
Example of my code for switching menu bar on another set:

```
void CMyFrame::OnSetMode(bool bMode) {
    const UINT nSetID = bMode ? IDR_MAINFRAME_SET1 : IDR_MAINFRAME_SET2;
    m_MainMenu.SetDefaultMenuResId(nSetID);
    m_MainMenu.ResetAll();
}
```

Is this correct way and have not any resource leaks or bugs?

Comment: What if you hide one and display the other ?

Comment: @Blacktempel how can i hide menu bar ? it's singletone object for frame. you can't create two or more CMFCMenuBar for CFrameWndEx ...

Answer (score -1):

```
// Remove current application menu
CMenu* pMenu = GetMenu();
pMenu->Detach();

UINT menuID = bMode ? IDR_MAINFRAME_SET1 : IDR_MAINFRAME_SET2;

// Reset application menu
CMenu newMenu;
newMenu.LoadMenu(menuID);
SetMenu(&newMenu);
```